# Django: How to manually render each field of a form on a bootstrap template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've found this nice bootstrap template online and I want to use it as my template for updating a user profile, I have tried several methods I've found in here and also in youtube, but I still couldn't get it to work. Not only does the form isn't rendering, the updated profile is not being saved also when I click update. Could someone help me out what is the problem? and I do apologize in advance if I'm not making sense as english is my second langauge.

here is my view for profile update, I did not create a form for it as I've read online that I do not need to create a form for it to work, just need the model.

```
class TutorProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone number', 'current_address', 
    'image', 'bio']
    template_name = 'account/tutor_dashboard.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tutor-dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        fm = form.save(commit=False)
        fm.user = self.request.user
        fm.save()
        messages.success(self.request, f'Profile Updated!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

and here is some part of the template, I will not paste it all here as it is too long.

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row gutters">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <h6 class="mb-2 text-primary">Personal Details</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.first_name }}
                        <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}" placeholder="{{ user.first_name }}">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the form fields and render each label and input (or select etc.) manually.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="Your boorstrap classes">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For more details you can take a look at the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields